# Can we Use OnBlur prop conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I want to show a component when input is focused for eg:

[not focused state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSHiU.png)

when clicking text input it should show this component

[focused state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t3M4.png)

this piece of code is working now the problem is

=>I want to hide this component when user clicks outside component i.e I am using OnBlur for this
but when I click on explore button (inside the component which we are toggling) still it gets hidden

[instead it should show this while clicking on explore button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL24b.png)

here is my code

```
"use client";

import { useChat } from "ai/react";
import { Input } from "../ui/input";
import { useChatStore } from "@/lib/stores/chat-store";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { UploadIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";
import ChatOptions from "./chat-options";
import OptionCard from "./option-card";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import Explore from "./explore";
import MessageCard from "./message-card";
import { useHotkeys } from "react-hotkeys-hook";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

export default function Chat() {
  const exploreTexts = useChatStore((state) => state.exploreTexts);
  const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useChat({
    sendExtraMessageFields: true,
    body: {
      exploreTexts,
    },
  });

  const [selectedOptionVisible, setSelectionOptionVisible] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "instant",
    });
  }, [messages]);

  const setInputFocus = useChatStore((state) => state.setInputFocus);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const [isChatOptionVisible, setChatOptionVisible] = useState(false);

  useHotkeys(
    ["mod + k"],
    (event) => {
      event?.preventDefault();
      setChatOptionVisible(!isChatOptionVisible);
    },
    [isChatOptionVisible]
  );
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={cn(
          "sticky border flex flex-col max-h-[400px] overflow-auto gap-2 p-4 sm:p-6 bottom-10 shadow-2xl rounded bg-white transition-all",
          !isChatOptionVisible && "gap-0"
        )}
        onFocus={() => setChatOptionVisible(true)}
      >
        <AnimatePresence>
          <OptionCard
            active={selectedOptionVisible}
            closeHandler={() => setSelectionOptionVisible(false)}
            className="overflow-hidden"
            title="Explore"
          >
            <Explore />
          </OptionCard>
        </AnimatePresence>
        <div className={cn(selectedOptionVisible && "hidden")}>
          <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
            <motion.div
              key="modal"
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, y: "0%" }}
              exit={{ opacity: 0, y: "100%" }}
            >
              <ChatOptions
                onClick={() => {
                  setSelectionOptionVisible((prev) => !prev);
                }}
                className={cn(!isChatOptionVisible && "hidden")}
              />
            </motion.div>
          </AnimatePresence>
        </div>

        <div className={`gap-2 flex flex-col text-sm transition-all`}>
          {messages.map((m, i) => (
            <MessageCard key={i} role={m.role} content={m.content} />
          ))}
          <div ref={ref} />
        </div>
        <form
          className="sticky bottom-0 flex"
          onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
        >
          <Input
            ref={inputRef}
            placeholder="Ask a question..."
            className="sticky bottom-0 peer border bg-secondary border-r-0 transition-all rounded-r-none"
            value={input}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              if (e.key === "Escape" && inputRef.current) {
                inputRef.current.blur();
                setInputFocus(false);
              }
            }}
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="bg-secondary px-2 peer border-l-0 border rounded-r flex items-center"
          >
            <div className="bg-white rounded-sm shadow-md p-1">
              <UploadIcon className="size-4 opacity-50" />
            </div>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried using useEffect to conditionally render when state changes, Also tried useRef to refrence my input instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hiding the component when clicking outside, you need to add a `mousedown` or `mouseup` event listener to the document that checks if the click target is outside of your component. You should not use `onBlur` for the input element because it will trigger even when interacting with other elements within the same component.

First create a `handleOutsideClick` attach it to either `mousedown` or `mouseup` even on the document. Then use ref ( `containerRef` ) for container of you entire chat component to help determine if the click is outside. Finally inside a `useEffect`, add the event listener to the document and clean it up on mount.

```
export default function Chat() {
  // ... existing code ...

  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); // Ref for the chat container

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleOutsideClick(event) {
      // If the click is outside the containerRef, hide the chat options
      if (containerRef.current && !containerRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setChatOptionVisible(false);
      }
    }

    // Add event listener for mouse down
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleOutsideClick);

    // Clean up the event listener
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleOutsideClick);
    };
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this effect runs only once

  // ... rest of your code ...

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className="chat-container">
      {/* ... rest of your component ... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```